# Responsive Webdesign: What is the lowest resolution one should test a website with?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap to create an HTML 5 website that should run on modern desktop Browsers as well as Smartphones.

What would you say should be the lowest resolution I should test the website with (considering small Smartphone screens)?

Comment: You'd be hard-pressed to find a device supporting less than 240 pixel device-width. Even that width is very rare and 320px is where you truly need to start caring.

Comment: Check in project documentation which resolutions should You support. If theres nothing like documentation 320px is the lowest width You should consider.

Comment: 240px is the smallest.